# Need to override static variable

Tags: c#, .net, database, orm, derived

I've created abstract class `ORM` with access to database and few basic methods. Some of there are static, such as:

```
abstract class ORM {
  public static string TABLENAME;
  public static Connect db_connection = new Connect();

  public static List<List<object>> where(query)
  {
    string query = "SELECT * FROM `" + TABLENAME + "` WHERE "  " " + query + ";";

    List<List<Object>> objects = new List<List<Object>>();
    if(ORM.connect.Open())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, ORM.connect.connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        int count = dataReader.FieldCount;
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            List<Object> args = new List<Object>();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                args.Add(dataReader.GetValue(i));
            }

            objects.Add(args);
        }                
    }

    ORM.connect.Close();
    return objects;
  }
        ....

}
```

So, i need to call this method from Derived Class

```
List<List<object>> current_user_instance = User.where("name LIKE 'Josh'");
```

And in Derived class I've created static constructor

```
static User()
{
  TABLENAME = "Users";
}
```

And it works perfectly. But in another case, when I call this method like

```
List<List<object>> current_user_instance = User.where("name LIKE 'Josh'");
List<List<object>> current_user_articles_instance = Article.where("user_id = 20"); 
// in my Article class static constructor is present too.
```

the `TABLENAME` is not changing from `"Users"` to `"Articles"`, because it is one class instance.

Please, help me to find alternatives to my resolution

Comment: Make them all instance members, so you can take advantage of inheritance.  There is no need to make them static, and as you've found out, they don't work as you desire them to.

Comment: @dbugger I'm looking for alternatives to solve the problem, but towards the the static method where